# NSAttributedString just stroke outside of letters

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, stroke

As you known, NSStrokeWidthAttributeName will stroke outside & inside of letters. There is a way to finish my job:

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName value:strokeWidthNumber  range:fullRange];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSStrokeColorAttributeName value:strokeColor range:fullRange];
[attributedString drawInRect:rect];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSStrokeColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:fullRange];
[attributedString drawInRect:rect];
```

but there is also a performance problem.
is there a way to finish my job without performance problem?

Comment: Please be more specific regarding the performance problem. Does it take too much time to execute? If so, please add what you have measured and what would be an acceptable value.

Comment: @Codo the code draw twice & in my scene, there is a lot of message need to process, so this code will result the phone too hot! I use Time profiler find this problem

Comment: It's somewhat unlikely that your app is slow just because the text is drawn twice. You better provide the numbers you have measured. Your question has already been marked for review and is likely to be closed soon.

Comment: @Codo, i descript not so detail, NSAttributedString is in a custom UIView, and the UIView is a property of a UITableViewCell, UITableView will reload frequently, so draw twice create a performance problem.

Comment: @Codo, i just want to know: is there a better way to finish my job?